# Jsoup wrongly closes a tag and puts tag text out of tag

Tags: jsoup

I was parsing a feed but it wrongly closes a tag

```
<link />http://wwww
```

Here is my code for getting HTML from a URL

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(pURL).get();
    doc.outputSettings().outline(false);
    doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
    String html = doc.html();
```

It gives following XML

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?--><html><head></head><body><rss version="2.0">    <channel>
    <title>Fenopy rss</title>
    <link />http://fenopy.eu/ <----------@see this
    <description>Fenopy torrent rss</description>
    <language>en-us</language>

        <item>
        <title>Broken City 2013 CAMRip English</title>
        <guid ispermalink="true">http://fenopy.eu/torrent/broken+city+2013+camrip+english/OTU0MDI1MA</guid>
        <pubdate>Sun, 27 Jan 2013 19:23:21 GMT</pubdate>
        <category>Movies</category>
        <link />http://fenopy.eu/torrent/bnglish/OTU0MDI1MA <----------@see this
        <enclosure url="http://fenopy.eu/torrent/Broken-City-2013-CAMRip-English/OTU0MDI1MA==/download.torrent" length="783829383" type="application/x-bittorrent" />
        <description> Category: Movies&lt;br/&gt;Size: 747.5 MB&lt;br/&gt;Ratio: 60 seeds, 11 leechers&lt;br/&gt; </description>
        </item>
```

but when I open it in browser it shows correct xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" >    <channel>
    <title>Fenopy rss</title>
    <link>http://fenopy.eu/</link>
    <description>Fenopy torrent rss</description>
    <language>en-us</language>

        <item>
        <title>Broken City 2013 CAMRip English</title>
        <guid isPermaLink='true'>http://fenopy.eu/torrent/broken+city+2013+camrip+english/OTU0MDI1MA</guid>
        <pubDate>Sun, 27 Jan 2013 19:23:21 GMT</pubDate>
        <category>Movies</category>
        <link>http://fenopy.eu/torrent/broken+city+2013+camrip+english/OTU0MDI1MA</link>
        <enclosure url="http://fenopy.eu/torrent/Broken-City-2013-CAMRip-English/OTU0MDI1MA==/download.torrent" length="783829383" type="application/x-bittorrent" />
        <description><![CDATA[ Category: Movies<br/>Size: 747.5 MB<br/>Ratio: 60 seeds, 11 leechers<br/> ]]></description>
        </item>
```

I don't know what's going on. is there any bug in Jsoup 1.7.2 jar?
help me ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug. Your GDATA response content-type is `application/rss+xml`, so you have to specify your `Parser` is XML parser; otherwise, by default, it is HTML parser, which works differently.

```
    // load Document
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL_SOURCE).ignoreContentType(true).parser(Parser.xmlParser()).get();
```

> //If you set outline and prettyprint = true then you have to look for
>   \n and \t characters and you have to remove them so make them false

```
    // config output
    doc.outputSettings().outline(false);
    doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);

    // output result
    System.out.println(doc.html());
```

The result of `<link>` output correctly if you specify XML parser.